# Connect to sftp/ssh via nautilus during a VNC session

Tags: server, nautilus, vnc

Im having an issues where I cannot connect to an sftp/ssh server via nautilus/files during a VNC session.
When I am standing at the terminal it works just fine! But over VNC I get an error stating "This file server type is not recognized." See [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-July/msg03969.html). But it also works if I use x11vnc and connect to display :0, but will not work on any other vnc server (tigervnc, vnc4server).

Steps to recreate the problem:

```
1. install fresh ubuntu 14.04 desktop
2. setup and connect via vnc
3. try to connect to sftp/ssh via ubuntu files/nautilus
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Another symptom of what I believe the be the same problem: when you you to File-->Connect to Sever... in Nautilus, the dialog box comes up containing the message "Can't load the supported server method list. Please check your gvfs installation."  Using vnc4server and starting nautilus by typing "nautilus &" in a terminal window within the vnc desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1442134).  Before you launch nautilus, run the dbus-launch command in the terminal in your vnc session:

```
$ dbus-launch bash
$ nautilus &
```

Nautilus now behaves as usual when you type an "ssh://" or "smb://" address in the location bar.

Answer (score 0):

nautilus connect to server on AWS Ubuntu 16.04 with desktop and gnome classic did not work until executing dbus-launch bash

Comment: This seems to be something more along the lines of a comment to the accepted answer, rather than a stand-alone answer.